# How can I get my HDD to appear on the BIOS boot priority menu?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios, priority

▼ My Environment

Hard Disk : WD BLUE 2TB (model : WD20EZAZ)

Main Board : Z690 AERO D (Gigabyte)

▼ My Problem

I cannot select the HDD as a boot drive in BIOS setting. (I can boot from a SSD. The HDD is not on the list in BIOS boot priority option.)

I can detect the HDD in applications such as GParted and Disks in linux after booting from SSD.

How can I get my HDD to appear on the BIOS boot priority menu?

Comment: As answered below, thinking about "drives" has the hallmark of the old BIOS mode boot process. This has been relegated to the history's trash can many years ago. Many boards still allow emulating such mode (Legacy/CSM/"BIOS") but there's no point in using it with any modern OS, the last one that didn't support UEFI mode was Windows XP, out of support for many many years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be on the boot list, the disk must contain a bootable partition.

Your [motherboard](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z690-AERO-D-rev-1x#kf)
uses UEFI BIOS, so the disk must contain an EFI partition to be listed.

Comment: I have installed a bootable ubuntu 20.04 in my HDD but I can't see the HDD from the list of boot option. (only SSD is on the list of bootable options)

Comment: Please add to your post a description of how you have installed on the HDD and which version. Sometimes the BIOS lacks the necessary drivers for some disk, but GRUB should do better.